# How to read the mathematical expression “xʸ”(or “x^y”) in English, which x and y are any of the complex numbers or algebraic expressions?

Tags: mathematics, reading

For example, x=1, y=2, it is 1², how to read the expression?

Comment: You mean how to state the expression in English?

Comment: Very closely related (but, IMO, not a dupe):  [How to read exponential expressions, e.g., "2^16"?](/q/74169/26083)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to read mathematical expressions. For powers, you could say:

> x raised to y

> x raised to the power of y

> x raised to the yth power

[...]

If you're raising the number to 2 or 3, say x "squared" or "cubed" respectively. You could use any one of the above, as long as the listeners know the context is mathematical.

Comment: *X to the power of Y* is also fine, one doesn't need to say *raised*.

Comment: Or even "*x* to the *y*" at its simplest.